# Which is faster? Insert or update?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

For data base MySQL
I want to insert rows as fast, as it can be done.
Inserts will be executing in multithreaded way. Let it be near 200 threads.

There are two ways to do it, as I want to do:

1) Use simple Insert command, each Insert will be wrapped into transaction.

There is a nice MySQL solution with Batch Insert 
(INSERT INTO t() VALUES (),(),()...) but it can't be used, because of every single row must be independent in terms of transaction. In other words, if some problems appear with operation I want to rollback only one inserted row, but not all rows from the batch.

And here we can approach the second way:

2) Single thread can do the batch inserts with the fake data, totally empty rows except autoincremented IDs. This inserts works so fast, that we can even ignore this time (about 40 nano sec/row) in comparison with single Insert.
After batch insert client side can get LAST_INSERT_ID and ROW_COUNT, i.e. 'range' of inserted IDs. Next step is to do Update with data we wanted to insert before by ID which we can get from previous 'range'. Updates will be executing in multithreaded way. Result will be the same.

And now I want to ask: which way will be faster - single inserts, or batch insert + updates.

There are some indexes in the table.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.

You should be doing batch inserts.  If a `BatchUpdateException` occurs, you can catch it and find out which inserts failed.  You can however still commit what you have so far, and then continue from the point the batch failed (this is driver dependent, some drivers will execute all statements and inform you which ones failed).

Comment: The question was not about "batch insert" or "insert or update". BI - completely not suteable, and I have already meantioned it before. When I wrote it I wanted to bold it or CAPS it .. but I steel remember about strict moderators and other. But anyway, thank you very much

Comment: It's a serious answer, but you donot seem to appreciate the time I took to actually help **you** with **your** problem.  Even if it is not what you were looking for, you could have just not commented and ignored it.  Looking for a blacklist feature now...

Comment: Everybody spends his time for answering or asking.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the major cause of errors and whatyou want to do with the failed transactions, `INSERT IGNORE` may be sufficient:

```
INSERT IGNORE . . .
```

This will ignore errors in the batch but insert the valid data.  This is tricky, if you want to catch the errors and do something about them.

If the errors are caused by duplicate keys (either unique or primary), then `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is probably the best solution.

Comment: Ignoring errors is not suitable for my case, and I have already meantioned before about independence of every single row. No batch for real data, only batch for fake bulk.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

If there are secondary `INDEXes`, then the batch-insert + lots of updates is likely to be slower because it will need to insert index rows, then change them.  OTOH, since secondary index operations are done in the "Change buffer", hence delayed, you may not notice the overhead immediately.

Do not use 200 threads for doing the multi-threaded inserts or updates.  For 5.7, 64 might be the limit; for 5.6 it might be 48.  YMMV.  These numbers come from Oracle bragging about how they improved the multi-threaded aspects of MySQL.  Beyond those numbers, throughput flat-lined and latency went through the roof.  You should experiment with *your* situation, not trust those numbers.

Plan B:

If failed rows are rare, then be optimistic.  Batch `INSERTs`, say, 64 at a time.  If a failure occurs, redo them in 8 batches of 8.  If any of those fail, then degenerate to one at a time.  I have no idea what pattern is optimal.  (64-8-1 or 64-16-4-1 or 25-5-1 or ...)  Anyway it depends on your frequency of failure and number of rows to insert.

However, I will impart this bit of advice...  Beyond 100 threads, you are well into "diminishing returns", so don't bother with large batch that might fail.  I have measured that 100/batch is about 90% of the maximal speed.

Another tip (for any Plan):

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
sync_binlog = 0
```

Caution: These help with speed (perhaps significantly), but run the risk of lost data in a power failure.

Comment: I am very surprised with 48 and 64 thread limit. Where can I find the prove? How can I define actual value for MySQL 5.1 and 5.5 version? I have already that 5.6, 5.7 is better, but anyway

Comment: 5.0 was more like 8 threads; I don't remember about 5.1 and 5.5.  For a while, Percona's XtraDB plugin was the best available.  The numbers came from MySQL conferences where the developers brag about the great improvements they have made.  Or come from Facebook's engineers, who stress MySQL severely.  In any case, 200 is very likely to _hurt_ more than, say, 100.